# What should I use in place of 'assigns' when writing tests using Guard?

Tags: ruby, guard, ruby-on-rails-7

I am getting the error below

`Minitest::UnexpectedError:  NoMethodError: assigns has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it`

I however do not want to use the gem as this is was deprecated.

Here is my test

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do
  get signup_path
  assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
    post users_path, params: { user: { name: "Example User",
    email: "user@example.com",
    password: "password",
    password_confirmation: "password" } }
  end
  assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
  user = assigns(:user)
  assert_not user.activated?
  # Try to log in before activation.
  log_in_as(user)
  assert_not is_logged_in?
  # Invalid activation token
  get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
  assert_not is_logged_in?
  # Valid token, wrong email
  get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
  assert_not is_logged_in?
  # Valid activation token
  get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
  assert user.reload.activated?
  follow_redirect!
  assert_response :success
  assert is_logged_in?
end
```

I tried using assert_equal